# Importing provisioning-profile does not work

Tags: xcode8, ios10, provisioning-profile, bundle-identifier

I have an app that I've been testing on my device. Few days ago, I registered for Apple Developer Program so that I can put my app on App store. I'm also building backend on AWS that will send push notifications. In order to enable push notification in AWS, I need to upload P12 certificate in AWS and I'm using this [guide line](http://quickblox.com/developers/How_to_create_APNS_certificates) to create one. It all went well and I downloaded provision profile that I created in Apple developers page. I imported the provision profile in XCode(8.1) by unchecking "automatic manage signing" and importing the same provision file for both Debug and Release. But when I build the project, I get "*A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.*". If I change my bundle identifier name to the one I created on developers page, Xcode says identifier already exists. I cannot create the previous bundle identifier that I had been using on developers page either; it says identifier already exists. How do I import the provisioing profile that I created on developers page in Xcode? Or How do i make developer page to list the bundle identifier that had been using?